# How can it be solved using Dijkstra’s algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you are given a graph where each edge represents the path cost and each vertex has also a cost which represents that, if you select a path using this node, the cost will be added with the path cost. How can it be solved using Dijkstra’s algorithm?

Comment: This question as it is currently phrased is too broad.

Comment: Just split each node to two with the edge going from the first to the second with cost of this node and run Dijkstra on this graph.

Answer (score 1):

### First solution: duplicate the nodes to add an "internal" edge

Replace the non-oriented edges with oriented edges, and duplicate every node N into one "incoming" node Ni and one "outgoing" node No so that going through a node N in the original graph is equivalent to going through both nodes Ni and No in the new graph, and thus through the extra edge from Ni to No.

```
 A   B                     Ao           Ai
  \ /                        \         /
   N        ----------->  Bo - Ni - No - Bi   in the new graph, every edge is oriented
   |                         /         \      all the edges on this drawing are oriented left-to-right
   C                       Co            Ci
```

Make sure edges between non-twin nodes are always oriented  out-->in, and edges between twin nodes are always oriented in-->out. For instance there is an edge from Ni to No (twin nodes), and an edge from Bo to Ni (non twin nodes).

### Second solution: add one half of the code of the node to all its edges

- Add the cost of the source node to the cost of every one of its edges;
- Add the cost of the target node to the cost of every one of its edges;
- Add **half** of the cost of every other node to the cost of its edges.

Now you can check than in any path S-A-B-C-T, the costs of S and T are added once edge, and the half-costs of A, B and C are added twice.

Answer (score 0):

The cost that Dijkstra's algorithm assigns to each vertex is the cost to reach that vertex.  You just need to incorporate the vertex costs into that cost calculation.

If only edges have costs, then the cost to reach a vertex is the cost to reach the previous vertex plus the edge cost.

If the vertices also have costs, then the cost to reach a vertex is the cost to reach previous vertex, plus the cost of the edge and the new vertex.

Otherwise, it's exactly the same algorithm.